# PHP 7.2 on 2x Travis CI instances, one with extension and one without

Tags: php, travis-ci

I'd like to have two instances of a PHP 7.2 machine on Travis CI - one with bcmath installed and one that doesn't have it installed.

My .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: php

matrix:
  fast_finish: true
  allow_failures:
    - php: nightly
  include:
    - php: 5.4
    - php: 5.5
    - php: 5.6
    - php: 7.0
    - php: 7.1
    - php: 7.2
    - php: 7.3
      env:
        - TEST_COVERAGE=true
    - php: nightly
    - php: hhvm
```

So would I just add another `- php: 7.2` line to .travis.yml or what?

Per https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/ I can add extensions thusly:

```
before_install: echo "extension = <extension>.so" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
```

Thus it stands to reason that the following would be sufficient to remove them:

```
before_install: sed -i 's/extension = bcmath.so/#extension = bcmath.so/g' ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini
```

I could probably even target a specific version with that like so (untested):

```
before_install: if [ '$TRAVIS_PHP_VERSION' = '7.2' ]; then sed -i 's/extension = bcmath.so/#extension = bcmath.so/g' ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php.ini ; fi
```

But none-of that gets me two PHP 7.2 machines - I can use those lines to have a VM of one type or the other but not both.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can run vm in debug mode and connect to it via ssh for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jobs` instead of `matrix` in your `.travis.yml` - see [Build-Stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/). To remove the `bcmath` functions, which are pre compiled into PHP on travis, you have to compile it with an additional option on your own:

```
language: php

jobs:
  include:
    - &STANDARD_TEST_JOB
      stage: Test
      php: 7.2
      env: BCMATH="on"
      before_install:
        - |
          if [[ $BCMATH != "on" ]]; then
              export PHP_BUILD_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-bcmath";
              git clone git://github.com/php-build/php-build.git $HOME/.phpenv/plugins/php-build;
              travis_wait phpenv install 7.2.19;
              phpenv rehash;
              phpenv global 7.2.19;
          fi
          php -v;
          php -m;
    -
      <<: *STANDARD_TEST_JOB
      php: 7.2
      env: BCMATH="off"
```